# Table "myTable" not found error in while accessing the H2 DB

Tags: java, mysql, groovy, h2

I am using the H2 in-memory database in my grails project. My application is running properly with the H2 database.
I want to connect with the H2 database using groovy to get the data from the database .

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
    import java.sql.Driver

    class psqlh2 {
        static void main(String[] args) {
            def driver = Class.forName('org.h2.Driver').newInstance() as Driver
            def props = new Properties()
            props.setProperty("user", "sa")
            props.setProperty("password", "")

            def conn = driver.connect("jdbc:h2:mem:~/databaseName;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1",props)
            def sql = new Sql(conn)

            def query = "SELECT * FROM company"
            try {
                sql.eachRow(query) { row ->
                    println(row)
                }
            } finally {
                sql.close()
                conn.close()
            }
    }
```

WARNING: Failed to execute: SELECT * FROM company because: Table "COMPANY" not found; SQL statement:
 SELECT * FROM company [42102-199]
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "COMPANY" not found;

Please help me out.

Comment: another application is using the same database and there it is working fine.

Comment: if it's in-memory database - i don't see any `create table` between connection and select. so it's logical to have `table not found` error...

Comment: I have stored the DB in a file and I am accessing the database which is connected to the other project.
The project is creating the table and storing the data.

Comment: there is now way to specify file for the in-memory database. you could set only database name. to use file-based database remove `:mem:` from your url. see details in the documentation   http://h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases

Comment: thanks, @daggett for the answer but a have used **jdbc:h2:file:~/db/mydb**  also , But I am getting the same response.

Comment: Add to the file-based url `;IFEXISTS=TRUE` and h2 will throw an exception if file could not be opened.  `jdbc:h2:file:~/db/mydb;IFEXISTS=TRUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace **mem** to **file**

```
   def driver = Class.forName('org.h2.Driver').newInstance() as Driver
        def props = new Properties()
        props.setProperty("user", username)
        props.setProperty("password", password)
        return driver.connect("jdbc:h2:file:${absolutePath};DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;IFEXISTS=true", props)
```

- Also make sure use the same version of H2 jar, which is using by h2-server.